# GCC Source Code modifications in libstdc++-v3 not being shown

Tags: c++, gcc, std, rtti, abi

I am new to GCC Source Code. I am starting to do some simple modifications to the **libstdc++-v3** because I need to do bigger modifications for a project I am working on.

I downloaded the GCC 4.8.5 source code and added a print statement in `__cxxabiv1::__cxa_allocate_exception` function just to know when the function was being called. To test it, I did **make -j4** and afterwards **make install**. With this built version of GCC, I compiled a simple program that throws an exception. However, no print is shown.

Then I tried to increment a global variable, which was declared in the program I was trying to compile, in the same function. Using GDB I realized that the global variable was in scope but it was never incremented. Finally, I tried to write a message to a file but the file was never created.

I am sure that the function is being called. But I am not sure why it is not doing what it is supposed to be. If I put something incorrectly in the code it won't compile, but when it does modifications are not reflected in the behavior of the program.

I need to know whether I am doing something wrong to test the little modifications I am making or where I could read some kind of guide to start collaborating to the GCC Source Code.

Comment: Why are you using an old unsupported release?

Comment: You should read the documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your GCC/lib directory, otherwise your binary will use your system `libstdc++`.

An alternative way would be `-static-libstdc++`.